# Can I export modules from FS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, systemjs, commonjs

In my `models` **folder** I have a lot of files like ..

```
// Account.js
module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema)
...
// Rules.js
module.exports = mongoose.model('Rules', RulesSchema)
```

And in my `index.js` file (**same folder** `./models`).
The reason is to lookup all files in `./models` folder, and export as named export

```
// index.js
const mathJSFiles = /^[^index].*\.js$/gmi;
fs.readdirSync('.')
  .filter(file => file.search(mathJSFiles) >= 0)
  .forEach(file => {
    file = path.basename(file, '.js')
    exports[file] = require(join(models, file))
  })
```

So in another file `main.js` I **want to do** like that...

```
import * as Models from './models'
Models.Account
```

Or

```
import { Account } from './models'
```

This is possible?

Comment: What is `* as`? Are you just mixing ES6 with Commonjs modules? Actually it should work with a plain `const models = require('./models')`

Comment: Yea, sorry. I change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something like the following:

```
// main.js
var glob = require('glob')
  , path = require('path');

glob.sync('./models/**/*.js').forEach( function( file ) {
  require(path.resolve(file));
});
```